# Testing with Jest+Enzyme API Mock calls is not beeing run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a problem that I can't understand and I was hoping that someone could help me with.

This is my test: state.messages is an empty array and api.botReply is called 0 times when it is in the function to be ran.

state.typing is set to true so I know I run the function.

```
test('test to resolve data from botReply', done => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Bot />);

    api.botReply = jest.fn(() =>
        Promise.resolve(wrapper.setState({ typing: false }))
    );

    wrapper.instance().sendReply();

    setImmediate(() => {
        wrapper.update();
        console.log(wrapper.state('typing'));
        console.log(wrapper.state('messages'));
        expect(api.botReply).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        done();
    });
});
```

And this is the function that is run:

```
 sendReply = () => {
    this.setState({ typing: true });
    api.botReply()
      .then(reply => {
        this.setState({ messages: [...this.state.messages, reply], typing: false });
      })
  };
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `setImmediate`?

Comment: I was trying to make sure the data have been resolved and that was the solution I found googling, but maybe it's totally wrong.

Comment: I don't know the answer here, but I think that dropping this non-standard, not-well-supported function might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discarding promise chains and using random delays can lead to race conditions like this one.

Since a promise is provided in tests, it should be chained to maintain correct control flow. It's not a good practice to assign Jest spies as methods because they won't be cleaned up afterwards. A promise is supposed to resolve with `reply`, not set state.

It should be something like:

```
test('test to resolve data from botReply', async () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Bot />);
    const promise = Promise.resolve('reply')'

    jest.spyOn(api, 'botReply').mockImplementation(() => promise);

    wrapper.instance().sendReply();
    expect(wrapper.state('typing')).toBe(true);
    await promise;
    expect(api.botReply).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(wrapper.state('typing')).toBe(false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I feel like this is something to is easier to understand, the only thing I don't know where to call my setState instead cause toBe(false) will fail as it is now

Comment: You don't need to call setState anywhere. It's already called in sendReply that you're testing. You can try to add `wrapper.update()` before `expect(wrapper.state('typing')).toBe(false)` to be sure though it shouldn't be necessary. You can see that it works as is, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ewsycw

Comment: it doesn't help either weridly enough, state is still { typing: true, messages: [] }

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest Enzyme version. The answer contains workable solution. As you can see in a demo, it works as expected. It's specific to your case. Consider providing a way to replicate the problem.

Comment: everything is up to date but with some sleep I got it to work using your code, thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you sorted this out.